# python 'with' statement, should I use contextlib.closing?

Tags: python, with-statement, contextmanager

This is from [flask tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/tutorial/dbinit/#tutorial-dbinit) Step 3:

```
from contextlib import closing

def init_db():
    with closing(connect_db()) as db:
        with app.open_resource('schema.sql') as f:
            db.cursor().executescript(f.read())
        db.commit()
```

Regarding line 4, must I import and call 'contextlib.closing()'?

When I've learned about **with** statement, many articles said that it closes file automatically after process like below. (same as Finally: `thing.close()`)

```
with open('filename','w') as f:
    f.write(someString);
```

Even though I don't use that `contextlib.closing()` like below, what's the difference?
It's from version 2.7.6, Thank you.

```
def init_db():
    with connect_db() as db:
        with app.open_resource('schema.sql') as f:
            db.cursor().executescript(f.read())
        db.commit()
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes, you should be using `context.closing()`; your own version does something different entirely.

The `with` statement lets a context manager know when a block of code is entered and exited; on exit the context manager is also given access to the exception, if one occurred. File objects use this to automatically close the file when the block is exited.

The `connect_db()` function from the tutorial returns a [`sqlite3` connection object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#connection-objects), which can indeed be used as a [context manager](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager). **However**, the `connection.__exit__()` method doesn't close the connection, it *commits the transaction* on a successful completion, or aborts it when there is an exception.

The `contextlib.closing()` context manager on the other hand, calls the `connection.close()` method on the connection. This is something *entirely different*.

So, your second snippet may work, but does something different. The tutorial code closes the connection, your version commits a transaction. You are already calling `db.commit()`, so the action is actually redundant provided no exceptions are raised.

You could use the connection as a context manager again to have the automatic transaction handling behaviour:

```
def init_db():
    with closing(connect_db()) as db:
        with app.open_resource('schema.sql') as f, db:
            db.cursor().executescript(f.read())
```

Note the `, db` on the second `with` line, ensuring that the `db.__exit__()` method is called when the block exits.

Comment: I don't really understand your last statement (regarding ", db"). Could you elaborate how this works? Isn't db closed when the outer context (with closing...) finishes? Why pull db into the inner, nested context?

Comment: @DavidBarker: `with closing(connect_db()) as db` does two things: it creates a context manager that will call `close()` on the `connect_db()` result when exiting, *and* it returns that same object from the `cm.__enter__()` method, so `with` assigns that to the name `db`. Now, that object *itself* is *also* a context manager, so in the second `with` we ensure that `with` calls `db.__enter__()` and `db.__exit__()` too, because those control the transaction.

Comment: So the `closing()` context manager _only_ calls `close()` and doesn't call `__enter__()` or `__exit__()` (even if the object is itself a context manager) at the end of the block? That makes perfect sense - thanks for taking the time to reply to a comment on such an old post.

Answer (score 6):

The only thing done by the `with` statement is to call `__enter__` method before entering its block and `__exit__` method before exiting it.
If those methods are not defined the `with` statement won't work as you may expect. I don't know what is the return type of `connect_db`, but I guess that it could be many different things from different third-party libraries. So, your code without `closing` will probably work in many (all?) cases, but you never know what can be returned by `connect_db`.