# Python ftplib: How to correctly release connection object?

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I have seen code like this (Python 3 code):

```
import ftplib
from contextlib import closing

with closing(ftplib.FTP()) as ftp:
```

Is the usage of the `closing` method necessary? In an interesting [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20793386/2008247), we can read that in database connection objects the context manager's `__exit__` method does not close the connection (at least not for SQLite), but commits a transaction instead. Therefore, using the `closing` method is necessary.

How is it with the Python's FTP class?

Looking at the [sources](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/ftplib.py) of the Python ftplib, we can find this:

```
# Context management protocol: try to quit() if active
def __exit__(self, *args):
    if self.sock is not None:
        try:
            self.quit()
        except (OSError, EOFError):
            pass
        finally:
            if self.sock is not None:
                self.close()
```

The `quit` method is called hence I think that we don't have to use the `closing` method for Python 3. So we can use just:

```
with (ftplib.FTP()) as ftp:
```

Since `__exit__` method is missing in Python 2, `closing` is necessary for Python 2 code.

Is this correct?

Comment: You've answered your own question :) In Python2, just as you stated. There's neither a `__enter__` function or a `__exit__` function, there for the context handle won't do anything upon entering or exiting except assign the variable `ftp` in your case. So this is a inheritance and backwards compatible compliance thing. You can skip it if you're not interested in being a backwards ninja.

Comment: @Torxed Since Internet is littered with incorrect code examples (I understand that in many one-time small scripts you don't need to bother with such details) one is easily confused, so I wanted to have confirmation.

Comment: It's a totally fine question to ask :) I wrote up a little longer answer in case people stumbles across this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did answer your own question for the most part.
And as per discussed in the comments, it's a legit question since the internet is *"littered with incorrect code examples"*.

To clarify my short answer, this is a heritage issue where Python3 code won't perform as expected on Python2. So (good) examples on the internet will hopefully either include a explanation of the dangers of running the code in Python2.. Or they'll make the code backwards compatible with a small modification.

This is such a instance where `closing()` is used to emulate the new functions from Python3 when the code is run on Python2.

Python2 (ftplib) doesn't have either a `__enter__` or a `__exit__` function, thus rendering the context handle "useless" (except making it forward compatible, easier to read IMO and also it assigned the call to a variable, in this case `ftp`).
To make it un-useless the writer used `closing()` around the call to get the automatic closure as per Python3.

If you're **souly using Python3**, this is redundant and probably slows down your code (extremely little). And there for you can skip that particular piece of code if you're not looking to be backwards compatible.